# S3 bucket - Terraform: Plan shows inexistent changes, on default values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, acl, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to terraform and import an existing log bucket. The HCL code looks like the following and is a complete replica of what is up in production:

```
locals {
  bucket_name = "log-bucket-${var.environment}-${var.region}"
}

module "bucket" {
  source        = "git@github.com:mycompany/s3-bucket-module?ref=1.0.5"
  name          = local.bucket_name
  log_bucket    = local.bucket_name
  bucket_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Sid" : "AllowSSLRequestsOnly",
        "Effect" : "Deny",
        "Principal" : "*",
        "Action" : "s3:*",
        "Resource" : [*],
        "Condition" : {
          "Bool" : {
            "aws:SecureTransport" : "false"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
  grant = [
    {
      id          = data.aws_canonical_user_id.current_user.id
      type        = "CanonicalUser"
      permissions = ["FULL_CONTROL"]
    },
    {
      type        = "Group"
      uri         = "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery"
      permissions = ["READ_ACP", "WRITE"]
    },
  ]
  lifecycle_rules = [
    {
      id      = "log"
      enabled = true
      prefix  = "log/"

      tags = {
        "rule"      = "log"
        "autoclean" = "true"
      }
      transition = [
        {
          days          = 30
          storage_class = "STANDARD_IA"
        },
        {
          days          = 60
          storage_class = "GLACIER"
        }
      ]
      expiration = {
        days = 90
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After importing the bucket with `terraform import ...` and making a terraform plan I get the following changes:

```
  # module.s3-bucket-module.module.bucket.aws_s3_bucket.bucket will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
      + acl                         = "private"
      + force_destroy               = false
        id                          = "mycompany-log-bucket-myenvironment-myregion"
        tags                        = {}
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)
        # (6 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

Based on this plan, the terraform wants to perform two things:

```
      + acl                         = "private"
      + force_destroy               = false
```

but these are the default values, which I have never explicitly changed. I guess what I am trying to say is that in reality it doesn't seem to change anything, but rather explicitly set the default values.

This is confusing me, and since it is a production bucket I want your opinion before applying. Why are those two "changes" appearing there?

Comment: Hi , i guess there is an issue in Terraform https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6193 . 
I would try to specifically pass those variables in my s3 bucket resource, then import it again and see if it changes them.

Comment: "acl" attribute conflicts with "grant" attribute. One of the two must be defined

Comment: Therefore I cannot explicitly define ACL. I am just wondering if applying the plan will ruin something.

Comment: FYI explicitly setting `force_destroy = false` did not suppress the terraform warning

Comment: Hmm, you can check the s3 from the console. If the ACL is private you are fine to apply this terraform plan. I guess then you can check the next plan if changes again the bucket. 
Since its an update you will be fine

Comment: Those are default values for the API, but not for the UI. Assuming this bucket was created in the console, then that explains why the provider is attempting to make those changes.

Comment: @bembas Consider reading the answer, it may be interesting to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to the bug bembas mentioned in the comments.

I created a replica bucket and imported it.

---

## Step 1

Before applying the plan

```
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
      + acl                         = "private"
      + force_destroy               = false
        id                          = "mycompany-log-bucket-myenvironment-myregion"
        tags                        = {}
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)
        # (6 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

I run `aws s3api get-bucket-acl --bucket mycompany-log-bucket-myenvironment-myregion`
and got this response:

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "ID": "hidden"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "Type": "Group",
                "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery"
            },
            "Permission": "READ_ACP"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "Type": "Group",
                "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery"
            },
            "Permission": "WRITE"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "ID": "hidden",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

## Step 2

After applying the plan

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "ID": "hidden"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "ID": "hidden",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

## Step 3

Made a new plan, the resource wants to change the resource again!

```
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)

      + grant {
          + permissions = [
              + "READ_ACP",
              + "WRITE",
            ]
          + type        = "Group"
          + uri         = "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery"
        }
      + grant {
          + id          = "hidden"
          + permissions = [
              + "FULL_CONTROL",
            ]
          + type        = "CanonicalUser"
        }

        # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

After applying this second plan, everything is back to normal and terraform doesn't request changes anymore.

`No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.`

Answer (score 4):

16/11/2021

I guess there is an [open bug](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6193) and terraform see as update the following attributes :

```
 + acl                         = "private"
 + force_destroy               = false
```

In the specific tf resource, a workaround is to apply the update (bug) and then reapply for terraform state to be up to date.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, but as my answer indicates it is not exactly "safe to apply" - there will be temporary changes after the first appliance and revert back to normal after the second. Could you please edit it?

Comment: Yes you are right. :)